# NoMethodError in Instructor::CoursesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I tried to add image for new course, it popped up the error message `undefined method 'courses' for <User:0x00007fb62c5cf5f0>`. Could you please let me know what are the missing parts. Please check my code at `CourseController#create`, much appreciated.

[image]

> Issue: NoMethodError in Instructor::CoursesController#create

```
class Instructor::CoursesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def create
        @course = current_user.courses.create(course_params)
        if @course.valid?
            redirect_to instructor_course_path(@course)
        else
            render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

private

    def course_params
        params.require(:course).permit(:title, :description, :cost, :image) 
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you define `has_many :courses` in the User model?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it still popped up error message "undefined method"/Users/gladies/Desktop/Screen Shot 2019-05-26 at 11.37.24 PM.png

Comment: Could you please add User model code to the question?

Comment: Hello Vasilisa: here is my User model code:                                                  class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courses
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :enrolled_courses, through: :enrollments, source: :course

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def enrolled_in?(course)
    return enrolled_courses.include?(course)
  end

end

Comment: class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courses
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :enrolled_courses, through: :enrollments, source: :course

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def enrolled_in?(course)
    return enrolled_courses.include?(course)
  end

end

Comment: Try to stop rails server and run `spring stop && rails server`. I have no more idea what is going wrong here :(